# Query for extracting info from one table based on other

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I have two tables post and share, post has many share. I want to fetch all data in post table using userId(posted by owner user) and also check share table using same userid that is if some one shared post to other user, if any condition is true, I need to fetch data.

I want to fetch data in post table if posted by owner or shared by other user in share table.

Example :

**table name: post**

```
id(pk) postname userid
    1  abc       10
    2  xxx       10
    3  yyy       11
    4  zzz       12
    5  bbb       13
```

**table name:share**

```
id postid(fk) userid
1   3           10
2   4           10
3   3           11
4   1           12
```

**Expected output: example find by userid 10**

```
 id postname userid
  1  abc       10  // this record created by user 10 (owner)
  2  xxx       10  // this record created by user 10 (owner)
  3  yyy       11  // this record shared by other user to user 10.
  4  zzz       12  // this record shared by other user to user 10.
```

Comment: I  suggest to do two separate queries and UNION them.

Comment: @PM77-1 any other alternative way is there for post and share ?

Comment: I'm trying to make heads or tails of your question.  You have table 'post' which is a list of all posts, with the user who created it.  Then you have 'share' which is a list of posts which are 'shared' to other users.  I presume that postid in table share is equivalent to the primary key of post (id)?   Now.. your result is indicative of what?  I can't seem to figure this out.  half the results seem to indicate it is the post name along with the original user who created it, then the other half seems to show what users had the post 'shared' to them.

Comment: Nothing else comes to mind to satisfy your output requirements.  Why?  What's wrong with UNION?

Comment: I will implement this cencept in node.js, so two times I am going to find  server. I just trying single call .

Comment: @NateM. I have created sample data only, I want to fetch all the post by owner (ex user id = 10) and shared by some to other user(ex userid =10).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to print `created_by` and `shared_by` in two different columns as the example seems a bit confusing. Below query should produce the expected output in that case:

```
select p.id, p.postname, p.userid as 'created_by', s.user_id as 'shared_by'
from post p left outer join share s on p.id = s.postid
where p.userid = 10
order by p.id;
```

Comment: I am using mysql and I tried yourcode but I am getting all record. I want to fetch all post created by owner(ex: user id = 10) and shared by other user to user id 10.

Answer (score 0):

It finally clicked what you are looking for..

```
select p.id, p.postname, p.userid 
from post p 
join share s on s.postid=p.id 
where s.userid='10' or p.userid='10'
```

That should return all interactions related to a specific user (id 10), either if a post was created by that user, or a post was shared to that user.

Comment: thanks for your response. I tried userid 11, it return duplicate records.

Comment: Yes, it would, since there are two distinct rows with a user id of 11.  Maybe add `and s.userid<>p.userid`.  That would prevent adding rows where the post was shared to its own creator.